# How to use groupby and grouper properly for accumulating column 'A' and averaging column 'B', month by month

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data with **3** columns:

**date**: from 1/1/2018 up until 8/23/2019, column **A** and column **B**.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(600, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df['date'] = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='8/23/2019'))
df.set_index('date')
```

df is as follows:

```
date        A   B
2018-01-01  7   4
2018-01-02  5   4
2018-01-03  3   1
2018-01-04  9   3
2018-01-05  7   8
2018-01-06  0   0
2018-01-07  6   8
2018-01-08  3   7
...
...
...
2019-08-18  1   0
2019-08-19  8   1
2019-08-20  5   9
2019-08-21  0   7
2019-08-22  3   6
2019-08-23  8   6
```

I want **monthly accumulated** values of column **A** and **monthly averaged** values of column **B**. The final output will become a df with **20** rows ( 12 months of year 2018 and 8 months of year 2019 ) and **4** columns, representing **monthly accumulated** values of column **A**, **monthly averaged** values of column **B**, **month number** and **year number** just like below:

```
  month year  monthly_accumulated_of_A  monthly_averaged_of_B
0   1   2018    176                     1.747947
1   2   2018    110                     2.399476
2   3   2018    131                     3.976747
3   4   2018    227                     2.314923
4   5   2018    234                     0.464097
5   6   2018    249                     1.662753
6   7   2018    121                     1.588865
7   8   2018    165                     2.318268
8   9   2018    219                     1.060595
9   10  2018    131                     0.577268
10  11  2018    179                     3.948414
11  12  2018    115                     1.750346
12  1   2019    190                     3.364003
13  2   2019    215                     0.864792
14  3   2019    231                     3.219739
15  4   2019    186                     2.904413
16  5   2019    232                     0.324695
17  6   2019    163                     1.334139
18  7   2019    238                     1.670644
19  8   2019    112                     1.316442
```

​
 How can I achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) and [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html), for ordering add [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2018)
#changed 300 to 600
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(600, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df['date'] = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='8/23/2019'))
df = df.set_index('date')


df1 = (df.groupby([df.index.month.rename('month'), 
                 df.index.year.rename('year')])
       .agg({'A':'sum', 'B':'mean'})
       .sort_index(level=['year', 'month'])
       .reset_index())
```

---

```
print (df1)
    month  year    A         B
0       1  2018  147  4.838710
1       2  2018  120  3.678571
2       3  2018  114  4.387097
3       4  2018  143  3.800000
4       5  2018  124  3.870968
5       6  2018  129  4.700000
6       7  2018  143  3.935484
7       8  2018  118  5.483871
8       9  2018  150  5.500000
9      10  2018  139  4.225806
10     11  2018  136  4.933333
11     12  2018  141  4.548387
12      1  2019  137  4.709677
13      2  2019  120  4.964286
14      3  2019  167  4.935484
15      4  2019  121  4.200000
16      5  2019  133  4.129032
17      6  2019  140  5.066667
18      7  2019  189  4.677419
19      8  2019  100  3.695652
```

Comment: Wow. I really appreciate your help in resolving my problem.

Comment: @hyTuev -Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)